# How do I fetch data from an external api and store it in my local database? (javascript)

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, api, express

I want to fetch JSON from a website's endpoint and when once the data is fetched it should be simultaneously saved to my local database. I am using postgresql, node.js, and express.js

Editing this to make it more detailed because it was put on hold, but not sure what else to say beyond I am making ajax calls to get data from a web site, and I want to save that data to a local database that I have on postgres. I don't want to turn it into a CSV or save json files and then import.

I am open to different solutions lol.

Comment: [ask google](https://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enCA799CA799&ei=jkEtW4CKAoukjwTH9q6gDQ&q=How+do+I+fetch+data+from+an+external+api+nodejs&oq=How+do+I+fetch+data+from+an+external+api+nodejs&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.14716.15796.0.15940.7.7.0.0.0.0.138.781.2j5.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.669...33i22i29i30k1.0.KH7_XH8EH3M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that could work (not testet):
I am using here a fake online API (JSONPlaceholder) to simulate the use case...

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const pg = require('pg');

const app = express(); 
const connectionString = 'postgres://username:password@localhost/pg_demo_db' // your connection string 

app.get('/getdata/:id', function(req, res) { 
    if (!req.params.id) { 
       res.status(500); 
       res.send({"Error": "No ID"}); 
    } 
    request.get(
        // here I am using JSONPlaceholder API (Fake Online REST API for prototyping)
        { url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + req.params.id }, 
        function(error, response, body) { 
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
                // get data from body ... e.g. title
                const data = JSON.parse(body);
                const title = data.title || '';

                // store in Postgresql
                pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
                    done();
                    // Handle connection errors
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
                    }
                    // SQL Query > Insert Data
                    client.query('INSERT INTO titles(id, title) values($1, $2)', [req.params.id, title]);

                    res.json({title: title}); 
                })
            } 
        }
    ); 
});
```

Comment: thank you! everything in this answer is correct except for pg connect is now deprecated! so users should use pg pool!